# Responsive relocate sparse element in sidebar with only css

Tags: css, responsive-design

I want to make a responsive layout with one column on mobile and two columns on desktop.

In [very old article on web](https://www.edenspiekermann.com/insights/responsive-javascript-helpers/) the author uses javascript, but I guess with modern browsers you can only do this with css.

[Responsive layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuRxu.png)

The best result I've been able to achieve so far is with the following code, but in desktop mode I can't place the sidebar items one behind the other.

I think grid layout is not the right approach.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}
.main {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column: 1;
}
.sidebar {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column: 2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: auto;
  }
  .main, .sidebar {
    grid-column: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main"><span>A1</span></div>
  <div class="sidebar"><span>B1</span></div>
  <div class="main"><span>A2</span></div>
  <div class="main"><span>A3</span></div>
  <div class="sidebar"><span>B2</span></div>
  <div class="main"><span>C1</span></div>
</div>
```

Thanks to @vineet-tyagi suggestion I add below the solution which works well for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
<style>
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
  }
  .main {
    background-color: blue;
    grid-column: 1;
  }
  .sidebar {
    background-color: green;
    grid-column: 2;
    height: fit-content;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .container {
      grid-template-columns: auto;
    }
    .main, .sidebar {
      grid-column: 1;
    }
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      A1
   </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      B1
   </div>
    <div class="main">
      A2<br>A2<br>A2<br>A2
   </div>
    <div class="main">
      A3
   </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      B2
   </div>
    <div class="main">
      C1
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont understand what kind of placement you are trying to achieve exactly... u want to separate main on left and sidebar on right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "grid-auto-flow: dense;" also to the container class.

Comment: Work fine for me. Thanks.
I had to add "height: suitable content;" in the css desktop sidebar to prevent the height of the last element from getting stretched for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container { 
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    gap: 10px;
    grid-auto-rows: 100px;
}

.container .main,
.container .sidebar {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container .sidebar {
  background:red;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
  
  .container .sidebar {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
  }
  
  .container .sidebar:nth-child(3) {
    grid-row: 2 / 1;
    background: red;
  }
  
  .container .main {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
  }
  
  .container .main:nth-last-child(1) {
    grid-row: 1 / 1;
  }
  .container .main:nth-last-child(2) {
    grid-row: 2 / 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar"><span>sidebar - B2</span></div>
  <div class="main"><span>main - A1</span></div>
  <div class="sidebar"><span>sidebar - B1</span></div>
  <div class="main"><span>main - C1</span></div>
  <div class="main"><span>main - A2 </span></div>
  <div class="main"><span>main - A3</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need a generic css solution for html with dynamically generated elements of different heights. @vineet-tyagi solution covers my user case well and simply.